# Can not Access IIS site After IP Change

Tags: iis, webforms, dhcp

After publishing and hosting my asp net site  to IIS server I am facing a problem with change of IP Address of the computer that I hosted the site on. Every time the computer on/off a new IP Address is given to the computer and I can't access the site unless I changes the binding of the site to the newly given IP Address. I tried changing the IpV4 to use static IP Address, this time the site works but I can't access the internet. How can I make the site work with the DHCP given IP Address with out changing bindings every time after on/off???

Comment: From DHCP you can reverse a static IP for this machine, if you insist using an IIS site binding to an IP address. Otherwise, use all unsigned in your site binding.

Comment: As far as I know, you could use asterisk or  All Unassigned to achieve your requirement. They both simply signify that no IP is directly assigned to the domain and the host headers are what are used to pull the site. They work exactly the same and are mostly used in a shared enviroment where a number of domains need not have an IP assigned, just host headers.

Comment: how would the user know with which IP he/she should browse the site??...because the site has no domain name.